# Using hibernate save obj into database

Tags: hibernate

I'm using to use  entity mange.persist()  save an object into db.

Here is the parent class

```
public class CurrRequestProfileBO{
private CurrRequestDataSummaryBO currRequestDataSummary;
private List<CurrRequestLicenseBO> requestLicList;
private List<CurrRequestAddrBO> requestAddrList;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_PROFILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "REQUEST_PROFILE_ID", nullable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public CurrRequestDataSummaryBO getCurrRequestDataSummary() {
    return currRequestDataSummary;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_PROFILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "REQUEST_PROFILE_ID", nullable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public List<CurrRequestLicenseBO> getRequestLicList() {
    return requestLicList;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_PROFILE_ID", referencedColumnName = "REQUEST_PROFILE_ID", nullable = false)
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public List<CurrRequestAddrBO> getRequestAddrList() {
    return requestAddrList;
}
}
```

the saving for those two collection requestAddrList and requestLicList works fine. but it has error when saving currRequestDataSummary into db.

the error is

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("APS_DATA8_1"."CURR_REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY"."REQUEST_PROFILE_ID")
```

Here is the Lic BO which is working:

```
public class CurrRequestLicenseBO {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CURR_REQUEST_LIC_REQUESTLICID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CURR_REQUEST_LICENSE_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CURR_REQUEST_LIC_REQUESTLICID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "REQUEST_LICENSE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
public Long getRequestLicId() {
    return requestLicId;
}

public void setRequestLicId(Long requestLicId) {
    this.requestLicId = requestLicId;
}

@Column(name = "REQUEST_PROFILE_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Long getRequestProfileId() {
    return requestProfileId;
}
```

Here is the currRequestDataSummary class which is not working. Those two are very likely same annotation. I don't get why one is working, another is not.

```
public class CurrRequestDataSummaryBO {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CURR_REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY_REQUESTDATASUMID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CURR_REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CURR_REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY_REQUESTDATASUMID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
public Long getRequestDataSummaryId() {
    return RequestDataSummaryId;
}

public void setRequestDataSummaryId(Long requestDataSummaryId) {
    RequestDataSummaryId = requestDataSummaryId;
}

@Column(name = "REQUEST_PROFILE_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Long getRequestProfileId() {
    return requestProfileId;
}
```

Here is the full log, bo is the curr_request_profile_bo object

```
bo:CurrRequestProfileBO [requestProfileId=null, entityType=I, lastName=bbb, firstName=aaa, middleName=, orgName=, prvdrTypeCd=null, dob=null, npi=, ein=, ssn=ccc, createdBy=null, createdDate=null, updatedBy=null, updatedDate=null, userId=admin, currRequestDataSummary=CurrRequestDataSummary [RequestDataSummaryId=null, requestProfileId=null, status=PENDING, createdBy=null, createdDate=null, updatedBy=null, updatedDate=null], requestLicList=[], requestAddrList=[CurrRequestAddrBO [requestAddrId=null,requestProfileId =null, addrType=Other Address, addrln1=aaa, addrln2=bbb, city=ccc, state=AK, zipCode=null, country=null, createdBy=null, createdDate=null, updatedBy=null, updatedDate=null]]]
Hibernate: select CURR_REQUEST_PROFILE_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select CURR_REQUEST_ADDR_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: select CURR_REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY_SEQ.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into CURR_REQUEST_PROFILE (CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, DOB, EIN, ENTITY_TYPE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, NPI, ORG_NAME, PRVDR_TYPE_CD, SSN, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DATE, USER_ID, REQUEST_PROFILE_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into CURR_REQUEST_ADDR (ADDR_TYPE, ADDR_LN_1, ADDR_LN_2, CITY, COUNTRY, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, STATE, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DATE, ZIPCODE, REQUEST_PROFILE_ID, REQUEST_ADDR_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into CURR_REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY (CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, STATUS, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DATE, REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[2015-02-11 13:39:05] ERROR [http-8080-2] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:144) - ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("APS_DATA8_1"."CURR_REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY"."REQUEST_PROFILE_ID")
```

Here is the persist code I'm using:

```
em.persist(currRequestProfileBO);
```

Could anyone tell me where I did wrong.

Comment: You are trying to insert a `NULL` value into the column `REQUEST_PROFILE_ID` which a `NOT NULL` constraint is enforced to in the table `CURR_REQUEST_DATA_SUMMARY` available in the schema `APS_DATA8_1`. `EntityManager#persist(entity);` is not available in the present code snippets, by the way

Comment: Yes, I know the root cause of this. I update the section including the persist code. Please take look. Thanks!

Comment: If you know the root cause, why is this a question on SO?  Im confused >.<